# Macro that deletes all asterisk signs from cells

Tags: excel, regex, vba

Say I have a sheet, where the cells are mostly numerical characters only, but some cells unfortunately also contain "*".

I am new to VBA or macros in general and tried this:

```
Sub RemoveNonNumeric()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Selection
c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "[^0-9.,-]", "")
Next c
End Sub
```

My intent is to remove all non-numeric characters except ".","-" and ","

Either the code is faulty or my way of applying it is wrong.
Any help?

Comment: If you are new to VBA then try recording a macro that does what you want and inspect the code to see what methods are used.  Be warned, macro generated code is not good idiomatic VBA.  You should also install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and learn from the code inspections.

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Sub RemoveNonNumeric()

    Dim c As Range, regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
       .Global = True
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "[^0-9.,-]"
    End With
    
    For Each c In Selection
       c.Value = regex.Replace(c.Value, "")
    Next c

End Sub
```